# How to style pseudo element ::part() on ion-modal with conditions

Tags: css, typescript, ionic-framework

I have an `ion-modal` that previously has the css as below

```
ion-modal::part(content) {
  width: 300px;
  height: 480px;
}
```

I am required to create a condition **if A then the height becomes lower, but if B then the height stays the same**

I tried using the normal css

```
ion-modal {
 --height: 520px
}
```

but it doesn't work, and using it on the conditions also doesn't work.

I googled the solution, but comes up with nothing but styling on :before and :after

Comment: Are you using ModalController ?

Comment: show your code.